# Signing PDF with a certificate in a certificate store

Tags: pdf, itext, signing

I want to sign a PDF with a certificate in a certificate store.

I am using iTextSharp and iSafePDF for singing PDFs, it works OK when I sign using a certificate stored as .p12 file. But I don't know how to use the library for signing with certificates obtained from a certificate store. I have an instance of System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificate2, but the library uses a different object representation and I was not able to make it work. Can someone help?

Comment: For signing you always need a private key - not a certificate. The certificate is the public part which - if you could use it for signing then everybody would be able to to so.

Comment: I know, I have access to the private key of the certificate as well. I just need to know, how to use iSavePDF (or iTextSharp or any other .NET open source library) to sing the PDF using a certificate obtained from the certification store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, here is exactly what I was trying to find, the accompanying text is in Czech, but there is not much of it and the code that works is what matters.

[Signing PDF using a certificate in the certification store](http://blog.imp.cz/post/2011/09/27/Digitalni-podepisovani-PDF-souboru-v-C-cast-2)

Comment: +1 Took me a while to find what I was looking for in that link I ended up using this:  http://blog.imp.cz/post/2011/05/30/Digitalni-podepisovani-PDF-souboru-v-C

Comment: I am glad that my article and code served its purpose. The link is OK. I write about PDF signing in two parts, the first part using certificate from pfx file, the second using certificate from user certificate store.