# Signing a PDF with a PFX File

Tags: vb.net, itext, digital-signature

Is there complete and simple code available to show me how to sign a PDF with a pfx file?  the following example only work with older versions of iText.  When I used an older version, this code corrupted my PDF file and it couldn't be opened by Adobe Reader.  And I'd like to use the most recent version of iText so my code will last into the extended future.

All I need to do is:
1) specify an existing PDF
2) specify the pfx file
3) specify the pfx password
4) specify and output file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at an official iTexSharp [SignHelloWorld](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/tutorial/signatures/chapter2/C2_01_SignHelloWorld/C2_01_SignHelloWorld.cs) code sample which does exactly what you need. More general information about digital signatures in PDF documents can be found in a great white paper called ["Digital Signatures for PDF documents"](http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures/) written by Bruno Lowagie from iText Software. More useful code samples can also be found in [iTextSharp SVN repository](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/tutorial).

Comment: links are broken now, but https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634254/186244 this has some example links.